# Encoding URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm unable to encoding data URI:

```
var uri ="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQo...";
var res = encodeURI(uri);
document.location.href = 'display.jsp?img='+res;
```

After encoding, I'm getting the same uri. `display.jsp` is landing as am empty page.

Comment: this is a JSP problem, not a JS problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no encoding happening because what you have there is already a valid, completely encoded URI.

If you want to use that as a parameter in an other URI, you should use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
document.location.href = 'display.jsp?img='+encodeURIComponent(uri);
```

Comment: display.jsp page landing as empty page. why

Comment: Maybe there's a mistake in the `jsp` code? You should [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), post the HTTP request and your serverside code there.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct to use `encodeURI()` as this function encodes special character except: `, / ? : @ & = + $ #`

Use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode these characters.

For more info check below link:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `encodeURI` function is for making a URL valid for a browser, not for formatting content into a URL (which is what you're doing).  A base64 string is already formatted in such a way that it registers as valid.  To encode it as part of the URL, you need to use `encodeURLComponent`.

Basically, just use:

```
var uri ="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQo...";
var res = encodeURIComponent(uri);
document.location.href = 'display.jsp?img='+res;
```

For more info, check out: [When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent/3608791#3608791)